# How to update parent price dynamically of product attribute?

Tags: 7, views, commerce, rules, hooks

I'm using [Drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), [Product attribute](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes) and [Product Bundle](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_bundle). Each attribute (which is a product bundle) has it's own price, After selecting an attribute on a dropdown list it does not update the price of the main product, it also doesn't show the price on the dropdown list. How do we show the price on the dropdown list and also update the parent product price before adding it to the cart?

**Example:**

Main - 10,000

Attribute 1.1 - 1,000 (selected)
Attribute 1.2 - 2,500

Attribute 2.1 - 5,000 (selected)
Attribute 2.2 - 8,000

What's currently showing for the main is: **Main: 16,000** (because of Attribute 1.1 and Attribute 2.1)

But if I select the other attributes, the Main/parent price won't update anymore. How can I make this work?

Just like the [Commerce Pricing Attribute](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes). The problem with my case is I don't use the [Commerce pricing attribute](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes) because I don't use the commerce product option.

If it's hook form, rules, ajax, or a view, can you give me an example on how this will be done?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Lots of people asking this kind of question today ... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185748/drupal-commerce-update-price-via-ajax

Comment: This type of question is extremely hard to answer in the SE format and would better be suited in the issue queue or in IRC.